# How to Join 3 tables by user id and return records where a link exists?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

users

- userid
- username

Appointments

- Appointid
- useridfk
- Appointname
- Start
- End

plinks

- pid
- useridfk
- link
- projectidfk

What i want to do is join all the table by the userid and display all the appointments where there is a link exists in plinks where the users username = Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`select b.* from users a join Appointments b on a.userid=b.useridfk join plinks c on a.userid=c.useridfk where a.username='Mike' and c.plinks is not null`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Appointments
INNER JOIN users
ON users.userid = Appointments.useridfk
INNER JOIN plinks
ON users.userid = plinks.useridfk
WHERE users.username = 'Mike'
AND plinks.link IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing the relationships between the table I would do it this way:

```
SELECT appointments.*
FROM users
JOIN appointments ON users.userid = appointments.useridfk
LEFT JOIN plinks ON users.userid = plinks.useridfk
WHERE plinks.useridfk IS NOT NULL
AND users.username = 'Mike'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select a.* from Appointments a inner join Users b on b.UserId = a.UserIdFk
```

inner join PLinks c on b.UserId = c.UserIdFk
where b.UserName = 'Mike' and c.Link is not null

Answer (score 0):

U can try this solved your problem...

```
SELECT * FROM Appointments as a INNER JOIN users as u ON u.userid = a.useridfk INNER JOIN plinks as p ON u.userid = p.useridfk
WHERE u.username = 'Mike' AND p.link IS NOT NULL;
```